# What would '34' answer?

Tags: pattern, password

Here's a riddle for you:

If you ask the question to the *1*, it'll answer:   **None of them.**
If you ask the question to the *90* , it'll answer: **6**
If you ask the question to *86*,   it'll answer  **All of them**
*966* and *972*  would also answer:  **All of them**
But if you ask the same question to *49*, you might get an answer such as : **4**

So, my question is, if you ask the question to 34, what would it answer?

Try to solve without the hint first. But if neccessary, here is a hint.

> add " + "symbol right before the numbers that you are asking to, and see what it looks like.

**Hint -2**

> Do not look for a pattern for numbers. Numbers do not generate series. They have other meanings if you apply the first hint. Such as: **+1 , +90, +972** etc.
> As Marius and Mae Culpa mentioned, the numbers represent country telephone codes.
> 1 - USA - None of them.
> 90 - Turkey - 6.
> 86 - China - All of them.
> 966 - Saudi Arabia - all of them.
> 972 - Israel - All of them.
> 49 - Germany - 4.
> 34 - Spain - ?
>
>  So, what kind of a question that we have to ask in order to get kind of responses. As you can see, israel, saudi arabia and china have all different answer from others, turkey germany and usa. So what would differ from these 3 from these 3.
>  My other hint to you is think about their languages-alphabet.

Comment: Are they supposed to have different quote conventions, e.g. '1', '90_', '86, 966, or is that unintentional/unimportant?

Comment: Nope, quotations are irrelevant. Let me edit these if its confusing.

Comment: I guess something to do with ISD codes of countries  - USA(+1), Turkey (+90), China(+86), Saudi Arabia(+966), Israel(+(972), Germany(+49) ... so +34 corresponds to Spain :-)

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Ninja'd by Marius :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last hint was a bit of a giveaway. 34 would probably answer:

> **1**. (See below for how accurate this is.)

The answer is ...

> ... how many of the letters that the language of the country with the respective telephone prefixes uses are not letters of the basic Latin or English alphabet. (See Marius's answer for a list of prefixes.)
>
>  **Hebrew**, **Arabic** and the variants of **Chinese** use non-Latin writing systems, so the answer is "all of them".
>
>  English, Turkish, German and Spanish use Latin letters with some special letters:
>
>  **English** basically uses only the 26 base letters A to Z, although accented letters can appear in foreign words such as *façade* or *café*.
>
>  **Turkish** does not use all of the 26 base letters, but it add six to the alphabet: Ç, Ş, Ğ, İ, Ö, Ü. (The dotted I is distinct from the dotless I, so that capitalising the i does not make it lose the dot, so the Turkish I isn't equivalent to the Latin I and could be a seventh extra letter.)
>
>  **German** uses all 26 letters and has 3 umlauts (Ä, Ö, Ü) and the special letter Eszett (ß). The Eszett exists only in lower case (although there are movements to provide a capital form) and it isn't used in Swiss German.
>
>  **Spanish** uses all 26 letters and has one special letter, the Ñ. (CH and LL are often considered letters in their own right, but these are written with two glyphs. The accent is used to mark a stressed syllable, but accented letters aren't counted as spacial letters.
>
>  Spanish (or Castilian) isn't the only language spoken in Spain, however: Languages such as Galician, Basque and Catalan may also contribute special letters. For exaple, Catalan has the C with cedilla, Ç (but Wikipedia tells me that it isn't counted as extra letter).
>
>  So, yeah, **1** is probably a good answer.

Comment: Correct! I gave the last hint, thinking that the question might be too general and broad, so i wanted to make it more specific. But still i thought this was quite hard to specify .I appreciate your great answer and the clear explanation!

Answer (score 6):

Partial to get the ball rolling:

> The numbers represent phone number prefixes for different countries.
>  Here is the list and the corresponding answer to "the question"
>
>  1 - USA - None of them
>  90 - Turkey - 6
>  86 - China - All of them
>  966 - Saudi Arabia - all of them
>  972 - Israel - All of them
>  49 - Germany - 4
>  34 - Spain - ?

Comment: Great. Here goes the part 1. Now i am giving an another hint according to the info that you have found